# Jquery is not working on Leaflet popups

Tags: jquery, ajax, leaflet

In my project i m using the leaflet maps..
In that i make a leaflet popup, content from ajax function, in popup i  placed a slimscroll jquery plugin, but that plugin is not working for me.Then i try to add a click event jquery like

```
<script>
$('#elem').click(function(){
 //code
});
</script>
```

,but that also don't working...Is there is other ways to handle this jquery in my code..Or anyone knows how to handle jquery in the leaflet popups..???

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add `$(document).ready()` after `<script>`

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#elem').click(function(){
       //code
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: not working...i think the problem is in the leaflet configurations...may be they set codes for avoiding the popup jquerys...

Answer (score 1):

Because the content is not in the DOM until the popup is shown, you should [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) in your Javascript.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '#elem', function() {
     //code
  });
});
```